# When I convert an object to json with json4s in a SBT task, it reports errors, how to fix?

Tags: json, scala, sbt, json4s

I'm writing a SBT task, which will convert some objects to json and output, but has errors. Code is:

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scalap" % "2.10.4",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.6",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-core" % "3.2.6",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-ext" % "3.2.6"
)
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := "json4s-210-test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

import scala.tools.scalap.scalax.rules.scalasig.ScalaSigSymbol

lazy val json = taskKey[Unit]("output a json with json4s")

json := {
  case class Config(name: String)
  case class Project(name: String, configs: Seq[Config])
  implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
  val project = Project("myproject", Seq(Config("conf1")))
  val json = org.json4s.native.Serialization.write(project)
  println(json)
}
```

When run `sbt json`, it reports error:

```
➜  json4s-210-test git:(master) ✗ ./sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/twer/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/twer/workspace/json4s-210-test/project
[info] Set current project to json4s-210-test (in build file:/Users/twer/workspace/json4s-210-test/)
> json
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:json for the full output.
[error] (*:json) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/tools/scalap/scalax/rules/scalasig/ScalaSigSymbol
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed May 14, 2015 1:19:58 PM
> last
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/tools/scalap/scalax/rules/scalasig/ScalaSigSymbol
    at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$ClassDescriptorBuilder$$anonfun$constructorsAndCompanion$3$$anonfun$13.apply(Reflector.scala:123)
    at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$ClassDescriptorBuilder$$anonfun$constructorsAndCompanion$3$$anonfun$13.apply(Reflector.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
```

But you can see I've alread add the dependency:

```
"org.scala-lang" % "scalap" % "2.10.4"
```

and even imported the required class in the build file:

```
import scala.tools.scalap.scalax.rules.scalasig.ScalaSigSymbol
```

Why is there such error and how to fix it?

---

Update: You can clone the code and try it from here: https://github.com/freewind/json4s-210-test